# jQuery menu aim without Bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create Amazon-like navigation menu using [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) but I don't want to include `bootstrap.css`.

This is the my simple html :

```
<ul>                
  <li>
    <a href="#">Department1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>cate21</li>
        <li>cate22</li>
        <li>cate23</li>
        <li>cate24</li>
        <li>cate25</li>
        <li>cate26</li>
        <li>cate27</li>
    </ul>                               
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#">Department2</a>
    <ul>
        <li>cate21</li>
        <li>cate22</li>
        <li>cate23</li>
        <li>cate24</li>
        <li>cate25</li>
        <li>cate26</li>
        <li>cate27</li>
    </ul>                               
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#">Department3</a>
    <ul>
        <li>cate21</li>
        <li>cate22</li>
        <li>cate23</li>
        <li>cate24</li>
        <li>cate25</li>
        <li>cate26</li>
        <li>cate27</li>
     </ul>                              
    </li>
 <li><a href="#">Department4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Department6</a></li>           
 </ul>
```

Does any one have any example with a simple css file without bootstrap. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The example I wrote below is pure css, with your modified html for better markup

first of all, here is the modified html:

```
<ul class="container">                
  <li class="container-child">
    <a href="#" class="title">Department1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="sub-title">cate21</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate22</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate23</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate24</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate25</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate26</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate27</li>
    </ul>                               
 </li>
 <li class="container-child">
    <a href="#" class="title">Department2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="sub-title">cate21</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate22</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate23</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate24</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate25</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate26</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate27</li>
    </ul>                               
 </li>
 <li class="container-child">
    <a href="#" class="title">Department3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="sub-title">cate21</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate22</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate23</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate24</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate25</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate26</li>
        <li class="sub-title">cate27</li>
     </ul>                              
    </li>
 <li class="container-child"><a href="#">Department4</a></li>
 <li class="container-child"><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
 <li class="container-child"><a href="#">Department6</a></li>           
 </ul>
```

and here is the css,

```
.container {
  min-width: 500px
}

.container-child {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 0
}

.title:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block
}

.sub-title {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

you can see it works live here: http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/zAqar

Please let me know if you have further questions :)